# Merge 2 dataframes of different sizes after a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> I'm trying to relate the groupby filtered dataframe to the original dataframe. After doing the groupby I lose some columns that I had in the original dataframe. The idea is to relate it back to their respective STATE and CITY values. But when I try to relate back the dataframe grows back to normal size with 18 rows. I just want the interface of the original dataframe to the final dataframe which contains 9 rows.

Original dataframe:

```
    |  COD      |STATE| CITY  |   AZIM | SET|TEC|
0   |ALAAD_0001 |AL   |MAC    |0       |1   |4  |
1   |ALAAD_0001 |AL   |MAC    |110     |2   |4  |
2   |ALAAD_0001 |AL   |ARA    |120     |2   |4  |
3   |ALAAD_0001 |AL   |MAC    |220     |3   |4  |
4   |ALAAD_0001 |AL   |MAC    |240     |3   |4  |
5   |BAPID_0001 |BA   |SAL    |20      |1   |2  |
6   |BAPID_0001 |BA   |SAL    |20      |1   |2  |
7   |BAPID_0001 |BA   |VIT    |100     |2   |2  |
8   |BAPID_0001 |BA   |SAL    |100     |2   |2  |
9   |BAPID_0001 |BA   |SAL    |210     |3   |2  |
10  |BAPID_0001 |BA   |SAL    |250     |3   |2  |
11  |BAPID_0001 |BA   |SAL    |250     |3   |2  |
12  |CEMBC_0003 |CE   |FOR    |90      |1   |4  |
13  |CEMBC_0003 |CE   |FOR    |80      |1   |4  |
14  |CEMBC_0003 |CE   |CAU    |160     |2   |4  |
15  |CEMBC_0003 |CE   |FOR    |160     |2   |4  |
16  |CEMBC_0003 |CE   |FOR    |170     |2   |4  |
17  |CEMBC_0003 |CE   |FOR    |280     |3   |4  |
```

> After groupby:

```
df_cut = (
    df.groupby(["COD", "TEC", "SET"])
        .AZIM
        .agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x).max())
        .reset_index()
)
```

```
    | COD       |TEC     |SET |AZIM|
0   |ALAAD_0001 |4       |1   |0   |
1   |ALAAD_0001 |4       |2   |120 | 
2   |ALAAD_0001 |4       |3   |240 | 
3   |BAPID_0001 |2       |1   |20  | 
4   |BAPID_0001 |2       |2   |100 | 
5   |BAPID_0001 |2       |3   |250 |
6   |CEMBC_0003 |4       |1   |90  | 
7   |CEMBC_0003 |4       |2   |160 | 
8   |CEMBC_0003 |4       |3   |280 |
```

> Expected output:

```
    COD        TEC  SET AZIM    STATE   CITY
0   ALAAD_0001  4   1   0       AL      MAC
1   ALAAD_0001  4   2   120     AL      ARA
2   ALAAD_0001  4   3   240     AL      MAC
3   BAPID_0001  2   1   20      BA      SAL
4   BAPID_0001  2   2   100     BA      VIT
5   BAPID_0001  2   3   250     BA      SAL
6   CEMBC_0003  4   1   90      CE      FOR
7   CEMBC_0003  4   2   160     CE      CAU
8   CEMBC_0003  4   3   280     CE      FOR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index):

```
cols = ["COD", "TEC", "SET"]
df_cut = (
    df[df['AZIM'].eq(
        df.groupby(cols)['AZIM'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().max())
    )].drop_duplicates(cols).reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`df_cut`:

```
          COD STATE CITY  AZIM  SET  TEC
0  ALAAD_0001    AL  MAC     0    1    4
1  ALAAD_0001    AL  ARA   120    2    4
2  ALAAD_0001    AL  MAC   240    3    4
3  BAPID_0001    BA  SAL    20    1    2
4  BAPID_0001    BA  VIT   100    2    2
5  BAPID_0001    BA  SAL   250    3    2
6  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR    90    1    4
7  CEMBC_0003    CE  CAU   160    2    4
8  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR   280    3    4
```

---

Explanation:

[`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) places the mode max at the end of each group:

```
df.groupby(["COD", "TEC", "SET"])['AZIM'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().max())
```

```
0       0
1     120
2     120
3     240
4     240
5      20
6      20
7     100
8     100
9     250
10    250
11    250
12     90
13     90
14    160
15    160
16    160
17    280
Name: AZIM, dtype: int64
```

A Boolean Index is created by comparing this to the 'AZIM' column to find the indexes where the mode max is located:

```
df['AZIM'].eq(
    df.groupby(["COD", "TEC", "SET"])['AZIM']
        .transform(lambda x: x.mode().max())
)
```

```
0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
12     True
13    False
14     True
15     True
16    False
17     True
Name: AZIM, dtype: bool
```

This is used to filter `df`:

```
df[df['AZIM'].eq(
    df.groupby(["COD", "TEC", "SET"])['AZIM']
        .transform(lambda x: x.mode().max())
)]
```

```
           COD STATE CITY  AZIM  SET  TEC
0   ALAAD_0001    AL  MAC     0    1    4
2   ALAAD_0001    AL  ARA   120    2    4
4   ALAAD_0001    AL  MAC   240    3    4
5   BAPID_0001    BA  SAL    20    1    2
6   BAPID_0001    BA  SAL    20    1    2
7   BAPID_0001    BA  VIT   100    2    2
8   BAPID_0001    BA  SAL   100    2    2
10  BAPID_0001    BA  SAL   250    3    2
11  BAPID_0001    BA  SAL   250    3    2
12  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR    90    1    4
14  CEMBC_0003    CE  CAU   160    2    4
15  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR   160    2    4
17  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR   280    3    4
```

Lastly [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) to remove duplicates and clean up indexes:

```
df[df['AZIM'].eq(
    df.groupby(["COD", "TEC", "SET"])['AZIM']
        .transform(lambda x: x.mode().max())
)].drop_duplicates(["COD", "TEC", "SET"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
          COD STATE CITY  AZIM  SET  TEC
0  ALAAD_0001    AL  MAC     0    1    4
1  ALAAD_0001    AL  ARA   120    2    4
2  ALAAD_0001    AL  MAC   240    3    4
3  BAPID_0001    BA  SAL    20    1    2
4  BAPID_0001    BA  VIT   100    2    2
5  BAPID_0001    BA  SAL   250    3    2
6  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR    90    1    4
7  CEMBC_0003    CE  CAU   160    2    4
8  CEMBC_0003    CE  FOR   280    3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join of your `cut_df` and original `df` to bring in the CITY and STATE. Try:

**UPDATE**

The rows for the join keys below are not unique in `df` so need to `drop_duplicates()`

```py
key = ['COD', 'TEC', 'SET', 'AZIM']
result = pd.merge(df, df_cut, on=key, how='inner').drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The output gives me a dataframe with 13 rows. I want 9 rows.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't realize the rows in `df` for those keys were not unique. You'll need to `drop_duplicates()` either before or after the merge.

Answer (score 0):

gp - your gropby dataframe

or - your original dataframe

````
```python
or_drop = or.drop_duplicates(subset=['CITY', 'TEC', 'SET', 'AZIM'], keep='first')
expected = gp.merge(or['COD', 'STATE'], how=inner, on=['COD'])
expected = expected.merge(or_drop['TEC', 'SET', 'AZIM','CITY'], how=inner, on=['TEC', 'SET', 'AZIM])
````

excuse, it's not checked by me